# How to configure Tomcat that just the users be able to see my webapps?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, configuration, html, restriction

Is there any way to restrict the guests to access to my webapps pages that I deploy into the Apache Tomcat 9.0?
For example I have a webapp like `localhost:8081/geoserver/web` then I want that just those geoserver users to be able to reload and see the `localhost:8081/geoserver/web` web-page!
Is that possible?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: How are you planing to identify requests coming from "those geoserver users" ?

Comment: In `geoserver` you just create the users with different Roles!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivlTPzd-8eo